# Change the value at an absolute word address

Tags: absolute, masm

How do you perform operations like change the value at an absolute word address?

Say you have some value at 5DAh and you want to count the number of zeros on that address, or move a value from one absolute address to another. How can one do that?

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer: You Can't

You might have a trick question in front of you (no clue, just my guess).

The physical architecture of the 8086 chip did not have that instruction.

As for your two specific questions...

"*...you want to count the number of zeros on that address...*"

That's somewhat ambiguous, in fact so vague that I can't understand it.

"*...move a value from one absolute address to another...*"

Good question. We'll do this in 32 bit, no, 16 and then 32 bit.

### 16 bit example

```
    Push    Si                      ;source index register
    Push    Di                      ;destination index register
    Push    Ax                      ;We'll use this for the transfer

    Lea Si, Where_The_Number_Is_Now ;You'll define this, somehow
    Lea Di, Where_We_Want_It_To_Go  ;You'll define this also, same thing

    Mov Ax, Ds:[Si]                 ;The "Ds:" may or may not be needed, be safe
    Mov Ds:[Di], Ax                 ;Probably do need "Ds:" for this instruction

    Pop Ax                          ;Do pay attention to the reverse order
    Pop Di                          ;...of popping the registers in exact
    Pop Si                          ;...opposite of how they were pushed

                                    ; And you are done
```

### 32 bit example

```
    Push    Esi                         ;source index register
    Push    Edi                         ;destination index register
    Push    Eax                         ;We'll use this for the transfer

    Lea Esi, Where_The_Number_Is_Now    ;You'll define this, somehow
    Lea Edi, Where_We_Want_It_To_Go     ;You'll define this also, same thing

    Mov Eax, Ds:[Esi]                   ;The "Ds:" may or may not be needed, be safe
    Mov Ds:[Edi], Eax                   ;Probably do need "Ds:" for this instruction

    Pop Eax                             ;Do pay attention to the reverse order
    Pop Edi                             ;...of popping the registers in exact
    Pop Esi                             ;...opposite of how they were pushed

                                        ; And you are done
```

Comment: _"Short Answer: You Can't"_. You can certainly read from and write to absolute memory addresses (e.g. `mov al,[5DAh]`, `mov byte ptr [5DAh],0`). Moving data directly from memory to memory with absolute addressing is not supported, though.

Comment: @Michael very good point, excellent observation. Your way uses two instructions and one register. You'll still need a push and a pop, for a total of four instructions, so you've beaten my answer by, whatever the cycle count is.  Plus 1 for you Michael

Answer (score 0):

To change a value at an absolute word address:

```
mov             byte ptr [5dah], 0
```

...or...

```
mov             word ptr [5dah], 0
```

---

To move a value from one absolute word address to another:

```
mov             al, byte ptr [5dah]
mov             byte ptr [1234h], al
```

...or...

```
mov             ax, word ptr [5dah]
mov             word ptr [1234h], ax
```

---

As for the other question, the one that asked how to count the number of zeros on that address, you were a little to vague.